# ipad viewport css ignore absolute elements

Tags: css, ipad, viewport

Have a website that i am trying to show the full width on an iPad ignoring the tree as shown in the screenshot so that the page appears centred

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/5709910/screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-30%20at%205.50.45%20PM.png

The tree is an absolutely positioned element.

How is it possible to set the viewport on iPad so that it ignores certain elements. When the page opens in iPad, i want the screen to be zoomed in to the width of just the footer bar.

Note that i cannot make the tree part of the background image as the tree needs to be in front.

It would be much appreciated if any one has any ideas to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the viewport width before the body ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=768">
```